# Geolocation to find nearest place

Tags: php, html, mysql, geolocation

I have a database of national park names (Alcatraz Island, Death Valley, Biscayne, etc.) which all have coordinates.

What's the simplest way for me to match the closest park in my database to their current location whether on a mobile device or on a desktop?

Comment: 1) get their location, 2) calculate distance to everything in the db, 3) `order by distance desc limit 1`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/

Comment: Do you have any code examples you can post that will show us what you have tried already?

Comment: See the implementation of the haversine formula here, https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use Google's Geolocation API to get the user's current location, then with some Javascript, you can determine the closest park.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what database you're using, but you might look into [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), an extension to Postgres designed to handle geographical data. You would be able to query the database for the closest locations to a certain point. The algorithms for doing so are built in to PostGIS. Otherwise, you might need an external library to do the calculations.